# I am getting: "eclipse class file editor source not found mac"

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, class

When I try to look at for example at methods available for String Class I am getting this error: eclipse class file editor source not found mac. Can someone help to fix it. I am using Mac
[see here the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wMna.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is building against or running using a JRE. Switch to using a JDK for both.

Comment: Can you pls point where i could switch to jdk?

Comment: @GunelHasan In the preferences in _Java > Installed JREs_.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the source code to be able to see the details of the classes/methods, sometimes it comes with you JDK installation, then you just need to point into your IDE, but you can also download it separately.